# Is checking the "I have read.." check box considered lying?

Tags: lying

Some websites ask to check a check box that says:

> I have read and agree to the terms

I always agree to such things without reading them.

Would it be haram if I checked the box even though I didn't read the content?

Note that it says: **I have read..**

Comment: I guess everybody does. But obviously it's better to read first. I have read such terms some times and hardly learned something important from that.

Comment: skimming through the text is considered reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my calculations it should not be haram. I am computer specialist and saying that kind of policies or terms and conditions scripts written so clear the clouded areas in the users head and make a ground for the law. It is like "this site uses your ip address and shares it with third party companies." It is not a trade secret. It means if you think your ip should not be shared with others then stay away from us. We wrote that here so you cannot sue us. Nearly all internet sites do these kind of practice. They need to earn money so many of them do this by giving advertisements in the site and advertisements need all kind of information you have, like your age, gender, specific interests and so. 
If you value your information and want to know what you can capable of, read terms and conditions and other papers and do not agree if you dislike it. Otherwise you cannot agree in particular you should be agree all of the conditions. If you want to open an account on Facebook most probably you won't read their many many pages of terms and conditions paper. There are privacy, terms, cookies links under the Facebook page. Click them you will see another world of what they do.
All in all, it is like "Hamama giren terler. (Turkish Proverb)" means "if you can't stand the heat get out of the kitchen". My point is if you want to enter the kitchen you know you will sweat and you agree upon this as a condition. In the computer world, It is like signing a paper before entering the kitchen that the kitchen is hot and you may sweat. 
So it is not cheating. It is for law. On the other hand a muslim should be sharp and clever, you may be cheated, checking the box may state that they can steal your money or track you... or something else.. 
These are my knowledge and opinions. If you find a verse of the koran I will obey it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, if you say to a child that come here I will give you a toffee if you not give him toffee then you mislead him. In Islam there is no permission of lie even in Jokes also...

### What is Lying?

Lying is the complete opposite of truth. So, anything that is untrue and deliberately intended to mislead another person is a lie. A lie, therefore, can be anything spoken or written that is totally or partially baseless, unreal, made-up, distorted or exaggerated; for example, if someone were to deliberately state that a five foot pole was a ten foot pole, then this would be a lie. Similarly praising someone out of proportion is a form of a lie.

Lying is not limited to the serious matters only but people also lie and make them as jokes. Even this is not permissible in Islam because even in joke, we can hurt someone or might be our own selves.

It was narrated that Ibn ‘Umar said:

> “The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, ‘I joke, but I speak nothing but the truth.’” (Narrated by al-Tabarani in al-Mu’jam al-Kabeer, 12/391)
>   This hadeeth was classed as hasan by al-Haythami in Majma’ al-Zawaa’id, 8/89, and classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani (may Allah have mercy on him) in Saheeh al-Jami, 2494)

### Joking

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Woe to the one who tells lies to make people laugh, woe to him.” (Narrated by Abu Dawood).

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, warning against this kind of behaviour which some jokers are accustomed to:

> “A man may say something to make his companions laugh, and he will fall into Hell as far as the Pleiades because of it.” (Narrated by Ahmad).

Source: [Islam Questions & Answers](http://islamqa.info/en/22170)

Comment: Can you (or anyone else) give a single example of a joke that does not involve telling an un-truth? What about storytelling? Was Dickens committing a sin by writing fiction?

Comment: see the answer now

Comment: I do all the searches but some says that story is right, but some same says it is a lie to mislead muslims... As a Muslims it is not important how it's invented, important is We should not celebrate it!!!